# Configure static resource folder external to web app in jetty 8

Tags: java, jetty, xml-configuration

I am having a static resource folder external to the web application and am trying to configure it in Jetty 8. So far I have tried the following.

1) I have added a context handler in jetty xml as following:

```
    <Set name="handler">
  <New id="Handlers" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection">
    <Set name="handlers">
     <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler">
      <Item>
        <New id="context" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler">
         <Set name="resourceBase"><SystemProperty name="JETTY_HOME" default="."/>/static/</Set>
        </New>
      </Item>
       <Item>
         <New id="Contexts" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection"/>
       </Item>
       <Item>
         <New id="DefaultHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler"/>
       </Item>
     </Array>
    </Set>
  </New>
</Set>
```

and I have placed static folder in inside jetty-distribution folder.

I have also tried placing the static folder as static.war inside the webapps folder and it is not accessible with /static.

2) I have tried adding/changing the xml in the /contexts folder in the jetty distribution. Even that doesnt work.

Also, in my jetty-web.xml I have a webappcontext registered as below:

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
 <Call class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log" name="debug">
    <Arg>executing jetty-web.xml</Arg>
 </Call>
 <Set name="contextPath">/security</Set>
 </Configure>
```

My static resource structure is as follows.

```
   static
     -css
       - <all css files>
     -images
       - <further folders and images>
     -js
       - <all js files>
```

I am new to jetty, and started working in it from past few days. Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks